# Querying from multiple tables with different columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I have data in two tables that I want to query from. Each table has a different number of columns, but they both have one column, vID, that I want to use for my query. If I was querying one table, I would use this column in my WHERE clause:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE vID = ?"
```

And then I would use that cursor for my listAdapter.

The problem is in the same list, I also want to show data from another table:

```
"SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE vID = ?"
```

Both tables have day, month, and year values that I want to use in my adapter, and a name column that I want to use.

I have tried UNION, but that returns an error because both tables have a different number of columns.

What should my query look like? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried joining the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns are indeed the same, you need to specify those in the select to use UNION

```
SELECT foo,biz,baz FROM table1 WHERE vID = ?
UNION
SELECT foo,biz,baz FROM table2 WHERE vID = ?
```

The error you're getting is because the two tables have different columns, you can still UNION them, but you have to specify how to align the two tables if their schema is not identical.

Comment: So for me it should be "SELECT name, day, month, year FROM Table1..." and " SELECT number, day, month, year FROM Table 2..."? I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: OK, it is working now. I needed to add "_id" to the select clause for each table because it wasn't returning all of the rows without it. I also added "ORDER BY year, month, day" to get the most recent on top and now it looks like everything is perfect! Thanks for the help!